# tkinter: очистка старых label виджетов при повторном создании на их месте новых

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Новичок в питоне и в программировании. Решил сделать простенький генератор паролей на tkinter и возникла проблема. В программе по кнопке создать пароли генерятся 10 label с текстом паролей, но если генерить второй раз на место старых паролей лепятся новые. Вопрос как убрать старые?

Вот код на создание label пароля (таких 10 штук, сделал не циклом из-за того что рядом еще кнопка копирования в буфер). Функция вызывается кнопкой создать пароли:

```
def make_psw_form(win):
    win.geometry('200x487')
    passwords = generate_random_password()

    psw_0 = Label(win, text=passwords[0], font=('Times', 15))
    psw_0.grid(row=2, sticky=W, pady=5, padx=5)
    copy_button_0 = Button(win, image=copy_img, command=lambda: pyperclip.copy(passwords[0]))
    copy_button_0.grid(row=2, sticky=E, pady=5, padx=5)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно сначала очитить Label от предыдущего текста.

```
psw_0['text'] = ''
```

И так для всех Label-ов.